# Dropbox download file or folder with id or link

Tags: java, dropbox

I want to download the shared folder from dropbox using id of the file/folder or the shared link.

**Requirement**

User will share the file/folder with application user and will provide the name of file/folder to the application. This folder will come to sharing namespace of application user.

Download can be based on file/folder name with owner name or file/folder id or shared link

**Problem**

Problem is sharing namespace does not have the download option and user namespace does not have shared files. And also can not download with shared link because user may have settings applied for logged in user view only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared link, you can download from it directly using the URL parameters documented [here in the Help Center](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-).

Note that this is subject to any access restrictions on the link. If the user has not configured it for you to have access, you'll need to ask them to do so.

Alternatively, you can download individual files from a shared link using [`getSharedLinkFile`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#getSharedLinkFile-java.lang.String-) in the [Dropbox Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java).

Or, if the content has been shared with your account as a shared folder, you can download it using [`download`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks Greg, Can we download the complete folder as a zip like we can download it directly from browser with the url ends with **?dl=1**

Comment: The `dl=1` parameter does work for shared links for folders, so you can use that. (The API itself doesn't offer equivalent functionality.)